# Can't deploy react with typescript, vite and supabase in netlify

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, supabase

No problem in my local development but i cant deploy it using netlify and it throws an error:

```
Uncaught Error: supabaseUrl is required.
```

My supabaseConfig file:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
const supabaseKey = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_API_KEY;
const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)
export default supabase
```

Here's my .env variables:

```
VITE_SUPABASE_API_KEY="mySupabaseApiKey"
VITE_SUPABASE_URL="mySupabaseUrl"
```

My .env is in the root directory, i also installed the dotenv package, i searched but still cant resolve this issue.

Comment: When is the error thrown? Is it when your application is being compiled? Or is it when your application is run?

Comment: the error is thrown when it runs, i want to deploy it by using netlify but it renders nothing and throws the error.

Comment: Have you configured your environment variables correctly in Netlify? You may not have committed your .env file into your repo (which is entirely normal because sensitive values should not be committed into your repo). However you may have forgotten to configure these variables for Netlify to access them. Please double check and also see [documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/environment-variables/#access-variables) from Netlify.

Comment: i did have them configured today and now it works, thank you. I didnt know you need to configure the .env files in netlify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your environment variables to the Netlify dashboard for this to work. You can read more about how to do this from the Netlify documentation website https://docs.netlify.com/environment-variables/overview/